# Why are educational objects classified as being holy?

Tags: belief, worship, practice

Whenever I have accidentally stepped on a book of any sort, or even a school bag; my parents have always said that I must ask forgiveness from god by placing my hand on the object first, then my forehead.

I understand that goddess Saraswati is the god of education, is this why Hindus have this tradition?

Comment: Because they are considered as being related to the Goddess of learning, knowledge etc Saraswati.

Comment: @Rickross Okay, so it seems like it is a simple answer. I thought there might be a deeper meaning.